# Un gramme ou une barrette

Tags: sens

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Marseille:

- Drug addict: Tu as quelque chose por moi?
- Drug dealer: Tu veux quoi?
- Drug addict: Un gramme ou une barrette. Ce que t'as.

Does "barrette" mean "a line of cocaine" here? I could not find that meaning neither in the Word Reference dict nor in the Larousse dict.

Comment: It's very frustrating to have this question downvoted without any reason. It follows all rules and recommendations of question creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, *barrette* means a piece of hashish, something like 2 or 3 grams.